# asking the name again if the first letter input is not Uppercase but the problem is i cant put another question in while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop that asks you to input the last name if you input the first name correctly. The problem is, it will ask for first name, but if I answer it in lowercase, it will still say that the first letter is not capital, but instead of looping it to firstname again, it goes down to last name and i also want to print it all together. How to do it in right way?

```
    while(true)
    {                                                    
        System.out.print("Please Enter Your Name  :");
        String firstName =xss.next();
        char oneLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isLowerCase(oneLetter))
        {
            System.out.println(oneLetter + " is not capital letter!" );     
            System.out.println("Please enter the name again:"); 
            
        }
       
        
        else
        {
            System.out.println();
            break;   
           
        }
        System.out.println("Please Enter Your Last Name");
        String LastName =xss.next();
        char secondOneLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(oneLetter))
        {
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(oneLetter + " " +" is not capital letter!" );     
            System.out.println("Please enter the Lastname again:");    
           
        }{System.out.print(lastName + firstName);}
```

Comment: You need to use a loop around that particular part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

surround the individual code segment that you want repeated input with the while loop like so

Also I'm assuming you want to check the last name in the second loop instead of checking the first name again

```
        Scanner xss = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Please Enter Your Name  :");
            firstName = xss.next();
            char oneLetter = firstName.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isLowerCase(oneLetter)) {
                System.out.println(oneLetter + " is not capital letter!");
                System.out.println("Please enter the name again:");
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            }
        }
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Last Name");
            lastName = xss.next();
            char secondOneLetter = lastName.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(secondOneLetter)) {
                System.out.println();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(secondOneLetter + " " + " is not capital letter!");
                System.out.println("Please enter the Lastname again:");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(firstName +" "+ lastName);
```

Comment: but i  cant print the first name and last name together because it says that the lastname and firstname cannot be resolved as variable. My bad i didn't state it clear

Comment: that's because your variables are declared inside the loop.

Comment: move them outside of the loops and you should print just fine (see my edits)